# Amazon EMR allocates conatainer with 1 core on slaves

Tags: hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have the strange behaviour that yarn cannot allocate all containers properly.
I have maximizeResourceAllocation to true and it tries if I start an m4.4xlarge slave instance to request for each executor container all 32 cores from yarn.
However that fails for one container because the applicationmaster master process uses 1 core.

1 container 1vcore for the master process
32 cores container executor 1
32 cores container executor 2
32 cores container executor 3 fails because yarn has only 31 cores left to give.

my Step should execute in client mode. It is the same with the Zeppelin instances.

```
HadoopJarStepConfig sparkStepConf = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
    .withJar("command-runner.jar")
    .withArgs("spark-submit",
            "--class", ".....",
            "--deploy-mode", "client",
            "/home/hadoop/jars/.....jar");
```

I use a bootstrap step to get the jars into /home/hadoop/jars, because if you want to use s3 paths only deploy cluster is allowed which would block one of my executors with the sparkContext process.

All this means if I only have one slave nothing happens at all. And if I have 3, 1 does not do any work. Which is a waste of money.
I could in theory calculate executor cores - 1 and force that setting in spark submit. But this is supposed to work.
How can I tell yarn to put this applicationMaster 1 core process on the master or not create it, or start executors with different core counts?
I only use 1-4 instances and effectively sitting idle is really ok.